# how to find memory leaks in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to find memory leaks in javascript or jquery.

i am working on javascript alot these days. I  moved from middletier to UI.so I want to know if there is anyway to find them.

thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting Javascript Memory Leaks & Optimizing Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954412/detecting-javascript-memory-leaks-optimizing-code)

Comment: And [What tools and techniques do you use to fix browser memory leaks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95326/what-tools-and-techniques-do-you-use-to-fix-browser-memory-leaks)

Comment: @ robert These links are enough, i will go through them. Thank you once again

Comment: @robert , this is out of context question, is there anyway in stackoverflow to add questions to my favorites.

Comment: Click on the little star below the voting number and arrows in the upper left-hand corner of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Memory Leak Patterns in Javascript** 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak/

> Plugging memory leaks in JavaScript is easy enough when you know what
>   causes them. In this article authors Kiran Sundar and Abhijeet
>   Bhattacharya walk you through the basics of circular references in
>   JavaScript and explain why they can cause problems in certain
>   browsers, especially when combined with closures. After seeing some of
>   the common memory leak patterns you should watch out for, you'll learn
>   a variety of easy ways to work around them.

Comment: thank you very much for the reference.Is there any tool where we can run our code and find it.

Comment: See the two comments I placed below your question.  They have links to tools you can use.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome has the ability to take heap snapshots and compare them, which can be used to detect memory leaks and analyse memory consumption in general. There is [an article about heap profiling at Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling) that explains everything.

Answer (score 1):

[Debug.js](http://blog.jetienne.com/blog/2013/04/23/debug-dot-js-global-detection/) does global leak detection and type checking.